# Why does openapi-generator not create a package.json with typescript-angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, maven, npm, openapi-generator

I am generating code for `typescript-angular` with the openapi-generator-maven-plugin like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/../my_server/openapi.json</inputSpec>
              <generatorName>typescript-angular</generatorName>
              <output>${project.basedir}</output>
              <npmName>myClientRest</npmName>
              <npmRepository>http://localhost:8444/repository/npm-releases/</npmRepository>
              <providedInRoot>true</providedInRoot>
              <apiModulePrefix>my</apiModulePrefix>
              <stringEnums>true</stringEnums>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

What I am missing now is a `package.json` file so that I could do a `npm install`.
From some older swagger examples it looks like with the swagger plugin a `package.json` file was generated.

So my question is why is the `package.json` file not generated and what could I do to get one?

The output of the generator run looks ok to me:

> [INFO] --- openapi-generator-maven-plugin:4.2.0:generate (default) @ client ---
>
> [INFO] OpenAPI Generator: typescript-angular (client)
>
> [INFO] Generator 'typescript-angular' is considered stable.
>
> [INFO] Hint: Environment variable 'TS_POST_PROCESS_FILE' (optional) not defined. E.g. to format the source code, please try 'export TS_POST_PROCESS_FILE="/usr/local/bin/prettier --write"' (Linux/Mac)
>
> [INFO] Note: To enable file post-processing, 'enablePostProcessFile' must be set to `true` (--enable-post-process-file for CLI).
>
> [INFO] generating code for Angular 8.0.0 ...
>
> [INFO]   (you can select the angular version by setting the additionalProperty ngVersion)
>
> [INFO] writing file C:\my-client-rest\api\default.service.ts
>
> [INFO] writing file C:\my-client-rest\model\models.ts
>
> [INFO] writing file C:\my-client-rest\api\api.ts
>
> [INFO] writing file C:\my-client-rest\index.ts
>
> [INFO] writing file C:\my-client-rest\api.module.ts
>
> [INFO] writing file C:\my-client-rest\configuration.ts
>
> [INFO] writing file C:\my-client-rest\variables.ts
>
> [INFO] writing file C:\my-client-rest\encoder.ts
>
> [INFO] writing file C:\my-client-rest.gitignore
>
> [INFO] writing file C:\my-client-rest\git_push.sh
>
> [INFO] writing file C:\my-client-rest\README.md
>
> [INFO] writing file C:\my-client-rest.openapi-generator\VERSION

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the description of the plugin is not very clear (at least to me), because it seems that:

```
<configuration>
  <npmName>myClientRest</npmName>
</configuration>
```

is wrong and should be replaced with:

```
<configuration>
  <additionalProperties>npmName=myClientRest</additionalProperties>
</configuration>
```

or with:

```
<configuration>
  <configOptions>
    <npmName>tmsClientRest</npmName>
  </configOptions>
</configuration>
```

to make the generation of package.json and tsconfig.json work.

So my original example should be changed to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
      <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.1</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/../my_server/openapi.json</inputSpec>
            <generatorName>typescript-angular</generatorName>
            <output>${project.basedir}</output>
            <configOptions>
              <npmName>tmsClientRest</npmName>
              <npmRepository>http://www.test-tms-archiv-net.de:8444/repository/npm-releases/</npmRepository>
              <providedInRoot>true</providedInRoot>
              <apiModulePrefix>tms</apiModulePrefix>
              <stringEnums>true</stringEnums>
            </configOptions>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I was facing the same issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813304/how-to-use-generated-angular-client-from-spring-boot-rest-api)

Comment: Per instructions here, is also possible to use a config file. Would be interested in the markup to get that working and where you put the config file in the java structure. 
https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/usage/